# Unable to install the Parse SDK on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, parse-platform

I'm trying to install the Parse SDK and I followed all of the steps outlined on the site, however, I got this error when I tried to import ParseStarterProject into Eclipse:

```
[2014-10-22 19:34:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] (Android SDK Manager:12042): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 2243 was not found when attempting to remove it
[2014-10-22 19:40:37 - ParseStarterProject] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'
[2014-10-22 19:40:37 - ParseStarterProject] Project compiler settings changed. Clean your project.
[2014-10-22 19:40:37 - ParseStarterProject] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'
[2014-10-22 19:40:37 - ParseStarterProject] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/matt/workspace/ParseStarterProject/bin/jarlist.cache
[2014-10-22 19:40:37 - ParseStarterProject] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'
[2014-10-22 19:40:37 - ParseStarterProject] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/matt/workspace/ParseStarterProject/bin/jarlist.cache
```

I've tried cleaning the project but I'm having no luck. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can right click your android project -> properties -> Android -> select Project Build Target. Then clean project. In the end, enter your Parse YOUR_APPLICATION_ID and YOUR_CLIENT_KEY. You should be good to go after these steps.